# How to type generic HTTP response JSON

Tags: go

Most response bodies I get back from a certain API have the following structure:

```json
{
    "size": 2,
    "values": [
        // values whose types differ based on the endpoint that was called
    ]
}
```

For example if I hit `/api/v1/cars` I'd get back:

```json
{
    "size": 1,
    "values": [
        {
            "make": "Honda",
            "year": 1994,
        }
    ]
}
```

Then if I hit `/api/v1/courses` I'd get back

```json
{
    "size": 2,
    "values": [
        {
            "name": "Spanish",
            "startDate": "2023-08-07T04:00:00Z",
        },
        {
            "name": "Business",
            "startDate": "2023-08-21T04:00:00Z",
        }
    ]
}
```

With generics it looks like it works fine with something like this:

```golang
type ResponseValue interface {
    car | course
}

type Response[T ResponseValue] struct {
    Size   int
    Values []T
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/_ipjpp4-LZE)

How would that have been accomplished before generics was introduced, without having to create types that duplicate values like `Size` (the real data has a lot more fields than just `size`)?

```golang
type carResp struct {
    Size int
    Values []car
}

type coursesResp struct {
    Size int
    Values []course
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/LD2ovLKFd5K

Answer (score 0):

You would have embedded the generic response stuff, something like

```
type Resp struct {
    Size int
}

type coursesResp struct {
    Resp
    Values []course
}

type carResp struct {
    Resp
    Values []car
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wrapping data structure is called an "envelope". These are common for APIs that returned paginated responses. Before go had generics, envelopes were wrapped with the interface type:

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type PaginationEnvelope struct {
    Items      interface{} `json:"items"`
    ThisPage   int         `json:"thisPage"`
    PageSize   int         `json:"pageSize"`
}

...

envelope := &PaginationEnvelope{}
persons := db.persons.retrieveAll()
envelope.Items = persons

return JSON(envelope)
```

Results in:

```
{
    "items": [
        { "name": "Alice" },
        { "name": "Bob" }
    ],
    "thisPage": 1,
    "pageSize": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `Values` field as type `any`:

```
type response struct {
    Size   int
    Values any
}
```

To unmarshal a `response`, set `Values` to a pointer of the desired type. The `json.Unmarshal` function decodes to that value.

```
func unmarshal(data []byte, pvalues any) (*response, error) {
    r := response{Values: pvalues}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &r)
    return &r, err
}
```

Use it like this:

```
respCars := []byte(`{"size": 1, "values": [{"make": "Honda", "year": 1999}]}`)
var cars []car
r, err := unmarshal(respCars, &cars)
fmt.Println(err, r.Size, cars)

respCourses := []byte(`{"size": 1, "values": [{"name": "Math", "startDate": "2023-08-21T04:00:00Z"}]}`)
var courses []course
r, err = unmarshal(respCourses, &courses)
fmt.Println(err, r.Size, courses)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/qVxYN4h4tlA